# $_file in PHP why this is not working?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I'm new to PHP and I wrote a simple code in PHP for file upload.but my code gives me an error.can someone help me to find the error 
here is my code
error gives as   Undefined index

```
<?php

$name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

?>

<form  action="unset.php"method="POST">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">



</form>
```

Comment: download file upload code and tutorial here http://blog.trofeosolution.com/index.php/blog/file-upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
    echo $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<form  action="unset.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks it's working but is it must to use if condition here? bcz I saw in a video tutorial they have just wrote as i did with out  if condition but it gives me error.your cord works perfect.any reason ?

Comment: You must echo variable to display data

Comment: @ Đức Đoàn Quang please check this ... https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=11&video=17073 why this is not working I did exactly like this

Comment: @Erandi Go to see that video

Comment: that code(code in video tutorial ) gives me an error called Undefined index for  these 3 lines 
   $name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
   $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

Comment: The code in that video, they forget to check isset submit form, so It will be appear Undefined index variables. That is error basic in PHP

Comment: did you check the video ? it don't show any error there

Comment: yes, I checked that video, but at the end of video, they didn't run on browser. So we đin't see it

Comment: @ Đức Đoàn Quang yeah but in the middle of the video they run it and no errors... anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: That's right. Because the upload image and submit form before create php code. Then they created php code, the browser is not reload. but we can't see it.

Comment: @ Đức Đoàn Quang yeah just now noticed and there they have added some in next video that's why they didn't give any errors ...Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: I saw the next video. The code checked isset before reload page. So we didn't see any errors.

Comment: yeah me too anyway now I know the reason.Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use enctype attribute of `<form>` which specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

```
<form action="unset.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also try to access `FILES` variables only if file is uploaded like

```
if(isset($_FILES))
{
   $name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
   $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add** `enctype="multipart/form-data"` into Form Tag

Answer (score 1):

**try this it wont give you undefined index Error**

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
   $name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
   $size=$_FILES['file']['size'];
   $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
}

?>
<form action="unset.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">



</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag like

```
<form action="unset.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Note:

1. The enctype attribute of the  tag specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form. "multipart/form-data" is used when a form requires binary data, like the contents of a file, to be uploaded
2. The type="file" attribute of the  tag specifies that the input should be processed as a file. For example, when viewed in a browser, there will be a browse-button next to the input field